# NoReverseMatch while rendering the Django admin screen?

Tags: django, rendering

Running Python 2.5 Django 1.2.4

Error message while testing basic setup. First time I enter the /admin URL in my browser, I get error message:

> In template c:\dd\ddproject\src\templates\admin\base_site.html, error at line 10
>
> Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
>
> Exception Location:    C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in render, line 385

Here's the code at line 10

```
<a href="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.logout %}">{% trans 'Log out' %}</a>
```

I'm reluctant to include my entire `settings.py` file. But to answer your next questions, here's the relevant settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 )

 ROOT_URLCONF = 'src.urls'

 TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
     "/dd/ddproject/src/templates",
 )

 INSTALLED_APPS = (
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.sites',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.admindocs',
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're including `settings.py` in your question without being prompted, you can't be that much of a newbie :-)

If you're not defining your own login/logout urls, just remember to include the `auth` urls in your `urls.py` file. Best to do this last:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... other URL defs and includes here ....
    (r'', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Jarret.   No I didn't have the auth urls in my urls config.   I had a r'' regular expression already defined to take me to my greeting screen (I was figuring it was like a wildcard for any url typed in that didn't have a matched regex.)    

Are you saying I could have 2 urls defined in the urls.py with a r'' regex?

Comment: Your suggested fix worked, Jarret.   I see now what the r' ' regex is too.   Lets me pull in lots more urls from 'django.contrib.auth.urls'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in urls.py:

```
#Session management
(r'^login/$','django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

Or maybe you are using

```
(r'^admin$',include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'^admin/$',include(admin.site.urls)),
```

instead of :

```
(r'^admin',include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this line to my urls.py and problem solved: 
`url('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),`
I am using Django 1.5

Answer (score -1):

What fixed this for me, was to use absolute paths in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py. So:

```
'myproject.myapp',
```

and not

```
'myapp',
```